# How to fix "Could not find compile target android-32 for modules :app" error in Android Studio?

Tags: android

[image: Android Studio]

I've created a fresh project using default templates with Android Studio.I've installed SDKs, Invalidated Cache, Changed project versions.

Comment: You need to install the API 32 SDK via the SDK manager

Comment: Hi @RyanM - I've installed every SDK available via the SDK manager. This did not solve the problem. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: you see the blue box in your screenshot, you need to setup the sdk, click on "Setup SDK" to do so.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

first you need to go to

File -> settings -> appearance & Behavior -> system Settings -> Android SDK

[image: Screenshot of the window]

then click edit Android SDK Location
[image: Android SDK Location]

click next it will download missing part of the projects

then go back to File -> settings -> appearance & Behavior -> system Settings -> Android SDK

from there just select the API level missing and it will start downloading it after you click on Apply

Comment: After hours of work, finally you saved me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to select Android Api for SDK in fail/project structure or Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue. It's showing that I have implemented some dependencies which require compileSdk 33. Go to your build.gradle(:app) and change the compileSdk 32 to compileSdk 33. I think it should work.